# Proof of Factor Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm following the proof of the Factor theorem in [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Polynomial_Factor_Theorem) but I don't understand how $\deg(X-r) = 1$.

Comment: Keep in mind that the degree of a polynomial (in $x$) is the highest power of $x$ that appears. What is the highest power of $x$ in the polynomial $x-r$?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on the degree of a polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial) might help.

Answer (score 1):

In a polynomial $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots a_1x + a_0$, if $a_n \not = 0$, then we say the polynomial has degree $n$. The polynomial $ax + b$ is a special case, and is of degree $1$. It has the special name "linear polynomial" too.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason that I can't fathom out, I was assuming that X in here is a polynomial(probably because I write polys in capital)! I was just subtracting r from that polynomial and thinking that ain't degree 1, stupid mistake.